# Firefox button tag height/width not correct

Tags: firefox, button, height, width

Hi the current code doesn't work in firefox:

```
<button style="border:solid 1px gray; width:50px; height:22px;line-height:22px; vertical-align:top;">Button too long</button>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j7das/)

As you can see in chrome the text is cropped to the width of the button
and in firefox it displays the text anyway...

Any idea how to fix this ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/djsbellini/sYJXn/

Just need this in the CSS:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I was about to comment myself on this with the exact same answer :) But I wonder if it is a bug from firefox tho... Thanks for your reply

Comment: Probably that's just a different default value, not a bug (but I agree that the overflowed button is usually undesirable). CSS normalize/reset would help with this kind of issue.